# Lock orientation in iOS9 with nav controller

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

I tried everything I could to figure this out myself, I must have spent more than 20 hours on it but I just can't.  I know this has been asked before but many answers are outdated and none work for me.  There are some that suggest using extensions but I am not familiar with them, so maybe I implemented them incorrectly.

I want my app to lock the orientation for different view controllers (herein I will abbreviate this with VC).  The app has a navigation controller, so I know this complicates the task.  My app is complicated so I don't think posting actual code would be beneficial.  Here is the outline of my app with the orientation for each.  If it has the navigation bar I put an -NB at the end.

VC-A Table VC, Portrait -NB.

VC-B Standard VC, Portrait.

VC-C Standard VC, Landscape.

VC-D Collection VC, Landscape.

VC-E Collection VC, Landscape.

VC-F Standard VC, Portrait-NB.

VC-G Standard VC, Portrait-NB.

There are various segues between them but they are all show segues.  This is done in XCode 7 and iOS9.  Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

Are you talking about the case where you have for example ViewController A-B-C in a NavigationController, but B should be locked to landscape, and A and C should be locked to portrait? If this is the case: how would you do the show-transition between them? I am almost positive that this is not supported for a Navigation Controller.

I've done something similar before. In that case I "faked" the transition to B by instead of pushing it, I presented it modally without an animation. (And locked the orientation for this ViewController B).

To go from B to C in this case, just dismiss B without animation and let ViewController A tell its NavigationController to push ViewController C without animation.